# How can I return just 1 parameter from a function that is passing 2 parameters in it, and be able to access it in another function (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access one parameter from a function and use it in another function but I can't access the parameter outside of its original function.  The other function is not able to see the parameter even when I return it.

```
function GiveBCount(a,b){
  a; //do something that has nothing to do with b. 
 //a is not a number
  var b = 0;
  b++;//increase b. 
      //b is a number.
  return b;
}

function TakeBCount(){
  if ( b > 0){
    //do something
  }
}
```

**What is expected is that** I want to be able to access the result of b that is in the GiveBCount() function inside of the TakeBCount() function

Comment: well where is a defined? b in the function has no relationship to the b outside

Comment: The outside `b` and the `b` inside `GiveBCount` are different variables

Comment: Thanks but how can I access the inside b though?

Comment: What is your desired output? What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you have `function` in `var showB = function GiveBCount(a,b);`?

Comment: @AdrianPop I edited the question.  I only used that to see if I could access the parameter outside the function.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I edited the question, thanks for that

Comment: Useful SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like:

```
function GiveBCount(a){ // no need to take b here as you are declaring below
  a; //do something that has nothing to do with b. 
  var b = 0;
  b++;//increase b. 
      //b is a number.
  return b;
}

function TakeBCount(){
var b = GiveBCount(1);
  if ( b > 0){
    //do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a way to achieve what you were trying to do with your code.
I have added some comments below. Possibly take a quick read of the difference between local and global variables :)

```
function giveBCount(a,b){
    b++; // b now = 1
    return b;
}

function takeBCount(a,b){
    var giveBCountResult = giveBCount(a,b); // You now have access to the value.
    // e.g
    console.log(giveBCountResult);

    return giveBCount(a,b); // going to return the result from GiveBCount
}

var aCount = 1; // Global variable
var bCount = 0; // Global variable that will be changed from the functions

var result = takeBCount(aCount, bCount); // Call takeBCount function.
```

Good luck and enjoy learning JavaScript :)